# CodeIgniter cannot load language files when using array

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am trying to load multiple language files in my CodeIgniter 3 project. Everything works fine as long as I load 1 language file at a time. When I try to load the language files using an array then it returns a `NULL` value.

```
// This works fine:
$this->lang->load('homepage_lang', 'dutch');
$this->lang->load('login_lang', 'dutch');

// This does not work:
$this->lang->load(array('homepage_lang', 'login_lang'), 'dutch');
```

According to the CodeIgniter documentation this code should work:

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html#loading-a-language-file

In their example code they don't have any other parameters, but even when I leave mine out (the 'dutch' one) I am still unable to use an array. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to remove the trailing `_lang` from the language file names. The rest of your code looks fine.

**EDIT**

While looking through the CodeIgniter 3 core source code I found the language load function:

```
public function load($langfile, $idiom = '', $return = FALSE, $add_suffix = TRUE, $alt_path = '')
    {
        if (is_array($langfile))
        {
            foreach ($langfile as $value)
            {
                $this->load($value, $idiom, $return, $add_suffix, $alt_path);
            }
            return;
        }
        etc...
```

This means that when the first parameter is an array it will loop the array. After looping it will return nothing to stop further execution of the function. I think that's the reason why you get a `NULL` value.

Even though the load function will return null, both language files will be loaded and available.

Comment: No joy, still doesn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Is your array named `$lang` in both files?

Comment: Yes. The two files are identical except for the array keys and values.

Comment: I've made an edit in my answer, hope it helps you out.